# Instafeed not working

Tags: instafeedjs

When I try the most basic embedding the js script provided by the instafeed site does not work.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed/instafeed.min.js"></script>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

<div id="instafeed"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'CLIENTID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What do I have to do so that the feed will display anything?

Comment: Is there anything in the browser console to give more information?

Answer (score 0):

You need a real clientID for it to display properly. Did you receive one from Instagram yet?

Comment: Yes the 'CLIENTID' was just to mask my real client id.